# PowerShell Remove Junction

Tags: powershell, junction

As of Windows 10 PowerShell is finally capable of creating Junctions and links natively.

Howerver the Remove-Item function seems to be unaware of the junction and tries to remove the directory asking for confirmation and if it should recursively delete items within.

So, the question is:
Is there a way to remove a junction using PowerShell native Cmdlets? (i.e. without calling cmd)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is there a way to remove a junction using PowerShell?

Currently, at least in PowerShell v5, [this is considered "fixed"](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/621). What you can do is use the `-Force` switch, else you will get an error calling the path an NTFS junction. The reason that I at least use the quotes on fixed is that using the switch will still make the message about children in the directory show up. Selecting Y will still only delete the junction in my testing using PSv5.

```
Remove-Item "C:\temp\junction" -Force -Confirm:$False
```

If that doesn't work for you or you don't have v5 you can use the .Net method to delete a directory. This appears to work correctly as well.

```
[io.directory]::Delete("C:\temp\junction")
```

Comment: Thx for the link.
Apparently it's still somewhat broken in PS5.1.

`New-Item -Type symboliclink -Path D:\test -Value D:\testtest`

`Remove-Item "D:\test"`
Fails due to missing Force parameter (after asking for confirmation):

`Remove-Item "D:\test" -Force`
and
`Remove-Item "D:\test" -Recurse`
Fails due to conflict between marker in request and analysis point (freely translated from german) after asking for confirmation.

`Remove-Item "D:\test" -Force -Recurse`
Fails the same but doesn't need confirmation.

Comment: With a junction however you can remove it without having to confirm by adding both force and recurse:

i.e.: `New-Item -Type junction -Path D:\test -Value D:\testtest`
`Remove-Item "D:\test" -Force -Recurse"`

Comment: While doing this command, I'm getting an error. (Run the PowerShell command in admin mode)
-----------
Confirm
The item at C:\Users\*******\OneDrive\Desktop\FolderToDelete has children and the Recurse parameter was not specified. If you continue,
all children will be removed with the item. Are you sure you want to continue?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): Y
Remove-Item : Access to the cloud file is denied
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item -path "C:\Users\*******\OneDrive\D ...

Comment: @JyothisTS I think your problem is slightly different in that it's not really a junction, but instead some special file attribute which makes the cloud-only files that have not been persisted to your drive impossible to delete via Powershell.

Best to ask the question yourself with some more context to it.

Answer (score 2):

have a try on this "command-let":

```
cmd /c rmdir .\Target
```

source:[Powershell Remove-Item and symbolic links](https://kristofmattei.be/2012/12/15/powershell-remove-item-and-symbolic-links/)

Comment: While that is technically correct, it's not really what I was looking for.
I've clarified my question to make it more clear I was looking for a PowerShell native Cmdlet and not a let-cmd-do-it hack.

Answer (score 2):

Simple command -

```
rm [path of file] -Force
```

Comment: You forgot to add `-Recurse`, but otherwise, yes you can of course use the shortcut as well.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old, but for anyone looking into this in 2023, you can use the following PS cmdlet-combination to remove a junction but not its contents :

```
$junction = Get-Item -Path <path_to_junction>
$junction.Delete()
```

That path is the actual junction path, not the parent path.

This can be condensed to :

```
(gi <path>).Delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

After search by Google for a long time, I found the answer:

```
function Remove-Any-File-Force ($Target) {
    if ( Test-Path -Path "$Target" ){
        & $env:SystemRoot\System32\ATTRIB.exe -S -H -R "$Target" >$null 2>$null
    } else {
        return
    }
    $TargetAttributes = (Get-Item -Path $Target -Force).Attributes.ToString()
    if ($TargetAttributes -match "ReparsePoint") {
        if ($TargetAttributes -match "Archive") {
            Remove-Item -Path "$Target" -Force
        } else {
            try {
                & $env:SystemRoot\System32\cmd.exe /c rmdir /Q "$Target" >$null 2>$null
            } catch {
                try {
                    [io.directory]::Delete("$Target")
                } catch {
                    Remove-Item -Path "$Target" -Force
                }
            }
        }    
    } else {
        if ($TargetAttributes -match "Directory") {
            Remove-Item -Path "$Target" -Force -Recurse
        } else {
            Remove-Item -Path "$Target" -Force
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with removing junctions.

```
# Check by only showing junction links: 
(Get-ChildItem . -Force -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LinkType -eq "Junction" -and $_.Attributes -match "ReparsePoint" }) | Select FullName, LinkType, Target

# WARNING: This recursively remove all junction links
(Get-ChildItem . -Force -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LinkType -eq "Junction" -and $_.Attributes -match "ReparsePoint" }) | Select $_.FullName | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```